# Nautilus keeps trying to access a folder that doesn't exist

Tags: 10.10, nautilus, troubleshooting

Whenever I boot into Ubuntu, as soon as I login, I get a dialogue window pop up that says *Couldn't find "/media/[long string here]". Please check the spelling and try again."*

Upon looking at my `/etc/fstab` file I found out that long string is actually the UUID of the root partition.

I also found out that exactly the same thing happens if I do `nautilus -q` in the terminal. I then created a folder `/media/<long string here>`.  Now, instead of getting that error dialogue box, a regular nautilus window opens at that folder (on both situations described above).

It is clear that whenever the nautilus process starts (which happens on login and on `nautilus -q`) it tries to access that folder instead of starting quietly. What's going on here, and how can I fix this? It doesn't really break anything else, it's just annoying.

EDIT:
Here is the output of `ls -al /dev/disk/by-uuid/`

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 180 2010-10-21 10:02 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root 120 2010-10-21 08:02 ..
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 2010-10-21 10:02 221643331643076F -> ../../sda1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 2010-10-21 10:02 34e5211a-ad8f-4ffe-b3f8-b70b767fd993 -> ../../sda5
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 2010-10-21 10:02 4b41a6d6-0a8b-4ece-a7c4-712901fbf7b0 -> ../../sda8
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 2010-10-21 10:02 7c1303c4-02c0-4970-b653-1c6bd78938fa -> ../../sda6
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 2010-10-21 10:02 9480DE4180DE2A0E -> ../../sda2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 2010-10-21 10:02 c8c3aef2-360d-4fbc-ac31-a4e4dc57c110 -> ../../dm-0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 2010-10-21 10:02 e08c11e3-1c5c-474c-a9d6-b7e7ba095fa7 -> ../../sda7
```

The fifth line of this output contains the UUID that nautilus keeps trying to open. `/dev/sda8/` is my root partition.
Here is the output of `/etc/fstab`

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid -o value -s UUID' to print the universally unique identifier
# for a device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name
# devices that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
proc            /proc           proc    nodev,noexec,nosuid 0       0
/dev/mapper/home   /home           ext3     defaults    1       2
# / was on /dev/sda8 during installation, with UUID=4b41a6d6-0a8b-4ece-a7c4-712901fbf7b0.
/dev/sda8        /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
/dev/sda6       none            swap    sw              0       0
```

As you can see I've got an encrypted home partition, a swap, and a root partition on the fstab file. Again, that UUID on the tenth line is the one nautilus keeps trying to open as `/media/<UUID>`.

Here's the error message I get, for reference:
[image: Error message.]

Comment: The long UID is probably something like a USB key or some other removable media. Do you have anything like that bookmarked in your places in the side pane of nautilus? For some reason nautilus is trying to access a removable device.

Comment: @Richard Holloway: According to fstab, the long UID is the UID of the root partition. Is there a command I can use to check UIDs? All my bookmarks are regular folders inside my home folder and the home foldr itself.

Comment: pasting the contents of /etc/fstab would be mighty helpful here, as well as the output of 'ls -al /dev/disk/by-uuid/

Comment: @nathwill: Updated the question to include that info.

Comment: This sounds like something is stuck in your session-start. You could try to clear all automatically starting programs from your session by opening `System -> Preferences -> Startup Applications -> Options`, close everything, then hit `Remember Currently Running Application` and logout and in again and see if it is gone.

Comment: i agree... there's nothing in fstab that would have it trying to mount the disk from /media.... the /dev/disk/by-uuid output shows that the UUID definitely belongs to sda8 which is your root partition according to fstab, but nothing in fstab is looking for anything in /media, so it's gotta be a bookmark in nautilus or a script from somewhere else... good luck, let us know if bobby's suggestion doesn't do it for ya.

Comment: It did. I had no reference to nautilus in my startup applications, and I had set it to NOT remember running apps between sessions. Still, doing what Bobby said solved it. I can't write an answer right now. If anyone writes an answer with Bobby's suggestion I'll accept it. If not, I'll write it tomorrow as soon as I can. Thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it's an issue with the startup applications. I am almost certain it was caused by copying my configs from my previous (lucid) instalation to this new one (maverick). Following Bobby's suggestion, here's what I did.

1. Open `System -> Preferences -> Startup Applications -> Options`
2. Close any currently running applications.
3. Hit `Remember Currently Running Applications`.